# How to "install" Action Bar Sherlock?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-library

I'm trying to build the sample project "Action Bar Styled" using the Action Bar Sherlock.

I download the .zip file containing ABS here http://actionbarsherlock.com/ but I can't figure out where to unzip so that it will appear on Project>Properties>Add library.

Can someone give me an hand?

Also, I read somewhere (can't find it now, sorry) that the current Android Compatibility library supports the Action Bar in pre 3.0 versions, so it has basically the same "effect" as Action Bar Sherlock - can someone confirm this? Which library should I install?

Comment: "I read somewhere (can't find it now, sorry) that the current Android Compatibility library supports the Action Bar in pre 3.0 versions, so it has basically the same "effect" as Action Bar Sherlock - can someone confirm this?" -- this is not true.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Didn't heard about Compatibility library that contains action bars, I've downloaded the last one few days ago.
Anyway, it's very simple, unzip the file IN(!!) your workspace, then create new android project, and choose "Create project from existing source", then choose the "library" folder in the folders you've just unzipped.

Right click on the action bar sherlock project, properties > android > check "Is Library".
Then right click on your project, properties > android > change the target SDK to 3.2 (API 13), and press add library and choose the sherlock library.

You change your project to 3.2 so the sherlock can work, but you can still use it down to 1.6, just write in your manifest this line:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4"
              android:targetSdkVersion="13" />
```

And be careful not to use API 13 code in your app.

I wrote this really fast so if you don't understand me feel free to ask, and if you still don't understand you can look at their web in FAQ there's a video that explains how to use it, step by step.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much!

"And be careful not to use API 13 code in your app." - Does this include Fragments?

Comment: By the way, I've done a lot of research about this and it's kind of drivind me crazy with doubt. I need to do an application with tabbed layout and dynamical listviews under each tab. Action Bar + Fragments would be the best option to do this ensuring maximum compatibility across API's?

Comment: I forgot to tell you that you don't need to put the compatibility package in your app because the sherlock library include this package inside. Of course you can use fragments, this is what this package is all about! just make sure not to use android.app.Fragment (API 13), but android.support.v4.app.Fragment (update package). And for your other question, yes, I got into Fragments few days ago when I wanted to use TabActivity and saw that it's deprecated, you can see the samples folder to see how to do this.

Comment: Do you have a link to that samples folder with tabs using Fragments? Thank you so much, this has been driving me nuts.

Comment: The samples folder is inside the zip that contains the "library" folder, just import it as you've imported library ("Create project from existing source") :) Just run the samples app and read the source and learn how to use it.