# SlidingMenu example: issue in import to eclipse

Tags: android

I found this SlidingMenu library that allows developers to create applications with sliding menus (like Google+, Facebook apps, etc). It is delivered along with a folder called example that contains a file `manifest` and `src` directory, so that I thought this to be an example to see it in action ... When I tried and imported this example to my eclipse I got this:

```
Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'homeAsUpIndicator'
```

Any suggestion for solving it?

Comment: Do you have a link to the place you found it?

Comment: Did you import the Library folder as well into Eclipse and linked it as  Library to the Example project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also had the same problem.

1) You should download and import SherlockActionBar to Eclipse. Get it from here http://actionbarsherlock.com/faq.html

2) Then you must install the SherlockActionBar as library. Here's how to do it:
 [How to "install" Action Bar Sherlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991113/how-to-install-action-bar-sherlock)

3) You will have several errors. Just follow this tutorial to solve all errors:
http://boroniatechnologies.com/installing-slidingmenu-android-library-and-example/

Thats it. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem so I removed this

```
<style name="CustomUp">
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/custom_up</item>
</style>
```

then cleaned the project --> no errors then put it back and reclean and it the error disappeared. I don't know how this helped but it did