# Android ActionBar Sherlock do not appear

Tags: android

I have instaled `ActionBarSherlock` from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991113/how-to-install-action-bar-sherlock) tutorial. The problem is that when I have instaled Sherlock, in 2.2 version ActionBar still does not show up. Then I tried to implement ActionBar from Java file, when I start my app it threws error because I need at least 3.0 version. The Main Activtity is `ListActivity`, so my question is how can i implement `SherlockActivity` to `ListAcivty` and do I need to do it?

Comment: Question is VERY confusing. Try to reformulate it. If there are no runtime errors, but action bar is not shown - the most probably you didn't set activity theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you should declare its theme in the manifest

```
   <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
```

then in each activity you want the actionbar there you should extend it to the actionbar sherlock.

```
public class xxxx extends SherlockActivity {
```

and for listview, you can use actionbar sherlock's one by using this

```
... extends SherlockListActivity {
```

and this is in the end of you acitvity if you are going to use actionbar sherlock's menu buttons

```
       @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {

            MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.MenuOfButtons, menu);
            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.idOfButton:
//action done
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this video tutorial:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1S9f7GQlWDg

You need to extend from SherlockActivity.

I am afraid you can't use sherlock action bar when extending from other class like ListActivity. May be some workaround of creating an inheritance heiratchy of ListActivity and SherlockActivity come handy but it will be very complex.

If you can't afford to avoid ListActivity, you can increase API level (I think 12) in your manifest and use the action bar provided by android API.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use this in manifest.Whether you applied this?

android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light"

Moreover declare this in Main Activity when you extend SherlockActivity

final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();

```
    // set defaults for logo & home up
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    ab.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
```